# How to use different definitions and packages in each of the included papers?

Tags: include

I writing my PhD thesis (using Overleaf, compile with XeLaTeX), such that each paper I wrote is a chapter of the thesis.  My problem is that the definitions and packages of the different papers clash.

**Is it possible that each section will use it's own definitions and packages**?  Something like: "include only for this section" command

Comment: I can relate to your situation. You mean include a paper as a chapter of the thesis?
Or including the papers in the appendix? I guess the first

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Yes, the first option. -added to the question

Comment: your choices are to include the tex sources and arrange that the package use doesn't clash (which is best normally, for example even if your papers used different math setup when published the thesis will look more coherent if the same fonts are used throughout) or you process each chapter as the original separate document, and then use pdf tools to stitch the pdfs together at the end.

Comment: The second solution sound easier however, it does not automatically produce TOC, list of figures and bibliography

Answer (score 2):

While LaTeX allows to reuse the code very efficiently, I think that in your case the resolution of clashes and definition across your papers (that is, chapters) will require at least some work. I say that because I've done the same thing, and many others did that before me and you.

Since your PhD thesis is not just a collection of you papers (even if most of the contents overlap), I propose the following workflow:

1. If you have published (or at least submitted) several papers, they will very likely use different document classes, with their relative commands. Start one by one. Copy the content (that is, not the preamble) of a paper in a file dedicated to that paper/chapter. The first compilation of the thesis master document will very likely throw errors. Solve them one by one by adding in your thesis' preamble the required packages/definitions. Repeat for every chapter/paper
2. If you are in a scientific field, try to [normalize](https://thesistips.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/step-3-of-your-literature-review-normalizing/) the notation (that is, use the same symbol for a given quantity across all the thesis). It is possible that you've used two different symbols for the same quantity in two different papers. Or that you've used the same letter in two different papers for two different quantities. The thesis should not have such discrepancies
3. Avoid repetition of information: every paper has the *introduction* (or *previous work*, you name it), which will very likely be similar for all the papers, while the presented results and the findings will differ from paper to paper. While the results will stay in their dedicated chapter, I guess that your supervisor doesn't want to read very similar introductions three times in a row ;)
4. Avoid repetition of content: deduplicate other material, like figures or tables, and use cross references, instead.

This is what comes to mind right now, based on my experience.